# Splitting words based on the occurrence of capital letter

Tags: c#, linq

From an external API which I am a consumer receives a category which is of string type.

Out of the values we get they have a common format which is like

- NewWest (The word with start with a capital letter and wherever the word should break they will continue it with a Capital letter).
- ABC(The word will be all caps)

What we are doing till now is take this category as input and break them into multiple words with space
using this method

```
public static string BreakCategoryIntoMultipleWords(string category)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            string formatedWord = string.Empty;

        if (category.All(c => char.IsUpper(c)))
        {
            formatedWord = category;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (char c in category)
            {
                if (Char.IsUpper(c) && builder.Length > 0) builder.Append(' ');
                builder.Append(c);
            }
            formatedWord = builder.ToString();
        }
        return formatedWord;
    }
```

The current method will return this value for the following input

- ABC(input) > ABC(Output)
- NewWest (input) > New West (Output)
- NewBellCan (input) > New Bell Can

There is a third format which has been noticed

- ABCXyxxx
- XCVbbbb
- RRDddddddvvvv

  The required output are:
- ABCXyxxx (input) > ABC Xyxxx (Since after capital letter X all letters are small means that word has broken)
- XCVbbbb (input) > XC Vbbb (Since after capital letter V all letters are small means that word has broken)
- RRDddddddvvvv (input) > RR Dddddddvvvv  (Since after capital letter D all letters are small means that word has broken)

How should I implement this in the existing method so that all three formats work correctly.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve the third format?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I added another else IF condition to check if there are more then one  letter all caps till the time there is a small letter start, since it is not working I have not added with the sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegEx approach: https://dotnetfiddle.net/42gyod

```
string result = new Regex("(?=[A-Z][a-z])").Replace(input, " ").TrimStart();
```

Explanation of the Regex

- `(?= )` positive look ahead - this matches the characters before the match
- `[A-Z][a-z]` matches exactly one capital and one small letter

so  this searches for a capital and a small letter and inserts a space before - see https://regex101.com/r/PCSlOy/1

Comment: It adds a space in the start only for this case when input = "JoeMark" for rest of the two cases it works perfectly.

Comment: With the TrimStart it solves this problem of space too. Can you please explain the regex in a few words.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @fubo answer, you could also use `Split` and avoid `TrimStart`:

```
var z = string.Join(' ', Regex.Split(s, "(?!^)(?=[A-Z][a-z])"));
```